# XSLT: Sort by the lower of 2 values

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have some XML that is formatted as follows:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <price>
      <orig>15</orig>
      <offer>10</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <price>
      <orig>13</orig>
      <offer>12</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 3</name>
    <price>
      <orig>11</orig>
    </price>
  </product>
</products>
```

I need to sort the products using XSLT 1.0 (in either ascending or descending order) based on their current price. My difficulty lies in the fact that I need to sort on the lower of the two possible price values `<orig>` and `<offer>` *if* they both exist.

For the above example the correct ordering would be:

- Product 1 (lowest value = 10)
- Product 3 (lowest value = 11)
- Product 2 (lowest value = 12)

Any help would be much appreciated, as I can't seem to find a similar question through the search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I. There is a general and pure XSLT 1.0 solution -- as simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <products>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
    "price/*[not(../* &lt; .)]"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </products>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**II. If `price` has other children in addition to `offer` and `orig`** -- in this case the general solution **I**. above (as well as the other two answers to this question) doesn't work correctly.

**Here is a correct solution for this case**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <products>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
    "sum(price/orig[not(../offer &lt;= .)])
   +
     sum(price/offer[not(../orig &lt; .)])
    "/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </products>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**III. If we know that `offer` never exceeds `orig`**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <products>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" 
         select="price/offer | price/orig[not(../offer)]"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </products>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**IV. Verification**:

All three transformations above, when applied to the provided XML document:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <price>
      <orig>15</orig>
      <offer>10</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <price>
      <orig>13</orig>
      <offer>12</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 3</name>
    <price>
      <orig>11</orig>
    </price>
  </product>
</products>
```

**produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>Product 1</name>
      <price>
         <orig>15</orig>
         <offer>10</offer>
      </price>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Product 3</name>
      <price>
         <orig>11</orig>
      </price>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Product 2</name>
      <price>
         <orig>13</orig>
         <offer>12</offer>
      </price>
   </product>
</products>
```

**Solution II is the only of the three that still produces the correct result when applied on this XML document** (added a `minAcceptable` child to `price`):

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <price>
      <orig>15</orig>
      <offer>10</offer>
      <minAcceptable>8</minAcceptable>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <price>
      <orig>13</orig>
      <offer>12</offer>
      <minAcceptable>6</minAcceptable>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 3</name>
    <price>
      <orig>11</orig>
      <minAcceptable>7</minAcceptable>
    </price>
  </product>
</products>
```

**Do note** that none of the other answers processes this XML document correctly.

Comment: +1 Very elegant - nice work, @DimitreNovatchev. I would argue, however, that Solution II is not appropriate to the question (as it addresses a situation never described by the OP) and therefore should not be used as evidence of inadequacy in other answers. :)

Comment: @ABach, You are welcome. As for the relevance, both solution 1. and 3. are exactly following the OP's XML document. Solution 2 gives us knowledge what to do in a slightly different situation, when other solution don't work. Knowledge is power, don't you thonk so?

Answer (score 6):

*(answer updated to include thoughts on both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0)*

**I. XSLT 1.0:**

Note that XSLT 1.0 does not have a built-in equivalent to `min()`; assuming your parser supports [`EXSLT`](http://www.exslt.org/), you can make use of its [`math:min()`](http://www.exslt.org/math/functions/min/index.html) function to achieve a solution quite similar to the below XSLT 2.0 variant.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0:**

Here is a solution that makes use of the XPath 2.0 aggregation function `min()`.

**When this XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <products>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product">
        <xsl:sort select="min(price/offer|price/orig)"
          data-type="number" order="ascending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates> 
    </products>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**..is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <price>
      <orig>15</orig>
      <offer>10</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <price>
      <orig>13</orig>
      <offer>12</offer>
    </price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product 3</name>
    <price>
      <orig>11</orig>
    </price>
  </product>
</products>
```

**..the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
   <product>
      <name>Product 1</name>
      <price>
         <orig>15</orig>
         <offer>10</offer>
      </price>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Product 3</name>
      <price>
         <orig>11</orig>
      </price>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Product 2</name>
      <price>
         <orig>13</orig>
         <offer>12</offer>
      </price>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: @MarkS - I've updated my answer to provide a possible XSLT 1.0 solution. Do you know: does your XSLT parser implement the EXSLT extension functions (or, in particular, the `math` subset of those functions)?

Comment: It does. Looks like this could be the solution. I'll have a play before I give any feedback. Many Thanks!

Comment: All works fine with math:min(price/*). Really helpful answer - thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

**An XSLT 1.0 solution that does not require EXSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="products">
        <products>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="product">
                <xsl:sort select="(price/*[not(. > ../*)])[1]"
                    data-type="number" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates> 
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```